# How to get all version info after `which -a`?

Tags: bash, xargs

I have installed some GNU packages on my macOS Sierra, which include `bash`,  `coreutils`, `sed`, `which`, etc. Now I need to check all version info of packages have the same name, i.e `bash`:

```
$ which -a bash
/usr/local/bin/bash
/bin/bash
```

I use `$(which -a bash | xargs -I % echo % "--version")` to want to *get two version info at one time*, but it just display the **first** bash's version, which equal to `/usr/local/bin/bash --version`.

Are there any way can do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `which -a bash | while read bin ; do "${bin}" --version ; done`

Comment: It works, too. Thank you. But I think `| sh` is easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append `| sh`:

```
which -a bash | xargs -I % echo % "--version" | sh
```

Comment: I only get 1 bash version with this. Shouldn't there be 2?

Comment: @pedromss: Show output of: `which -a bash`

Comment: 16:10:34 › `which -a bash` ==> 
`/usr/local/bin/bash` and 
`/bin/bash`

Comment: Ah nevermind it show both but immediatly on the next line and I though it was only 1 version! Can you explain why the `sh` tho?

Comment: It works. Thank you very much. But there is no space between two version info, I used `echo -e "--version\n"` to solve it, but the `echo` of macOS can't support `-e`, any idea?

Comment: I suggest to start a new question.

Comment: You're right, I have started a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46024482/how-to-separate-outputs-of-one-line-multiple-commands