# How to separate outputs of one-line multiple commands?

Tags: bash

I have installed some GNU packages on my macOS Sierra, which include `bash`,  `coreutils`, `which`, etc. Now I can use `which -a bash | xargs -I % echo % "--version" | sh` to check all version info of `bash`, but there is no separation between two version info:

```
$ which -a bash | xargs -I % echo % "--version" | sh
GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin16.3.0)
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
# There should be one or more blank lines as separation.
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin16)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

I tried `... echo -e % "--version\n" ...`, but it can't work. Please help me, thanks.

Comment: Generally speaking, `echo -e` is best avoided. See the POSIX specification for `echo` at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html, particularly "*Implementations shall not support any options*". `-n` is explicitly allowed (though not required; see later in that document), but anything else is a spec violation. Accordingly, bash *may or may not* support `echo -e`, depending on whether its compile-time and runtime options configure it to be compliant. See the APPLICATION USAGE section of the standard for a discussion of getting equivalent behavior from `printf`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a bit more control of the output, use a loop:

```
which -a bash |
while read cmd; do
    printf '%s\t----------\n' "$cmd"
    command "$cmd" --version
    echo
done
```

Comment: Why `which -a` rather than the shell-builtin `type`? And unless you use `IFS= read -r cmd`, then it munges input (stripping leading and trailing whitespace and removing backslashes). Granted, you *shouldn't* have an interpreter in a location that ends in a backslash, but... well...

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I only used `which` because that's what tho OP used. Any command that generates the paths for all instances of the utility would work.

Comment: @Kusalananda Thanks for your help. But I met an error `-bash: print: command not found` when I ran your code. In fact, I copied your whole code. What is the `command` means?

Comment: @liyang Ah, that's a typo. `print` should be `printf`.  `command` is an actual shell command that runs its first argument as a command. I will fix that typo now.

Comment: I removed `command` and the code works fine, is it must need?

Comment: @liyang One usually use `command` to execute a command and at the same time disabling aliases and shell functions with the same name. Since we're running a command with an absolute path here, you probably don't need `command`. It should have worked with `command` there as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'd write this as follows:

```
IFS=: read -r -a path_entries <<<"$PATH"
find "${path_entries[@]}" -maxdepth 1 -name bash -type f -exec '{}' --version ';'
```

Note:

- No use of `which`. This isn't a shell builtin in bash, so it gives you none of the benefits you'd get from `type` (ie. awareness of functions and aliases); and because its output is line-oriented, it can't unambiguously emit all possible filenames (such as those containing newlines -- which, yes, *are* valid).
- No reliance on line-oriented content, generally. When the placeholder (`{}`) is passed as a single token, `find -exec` substitutes the exact filename returned for that token. Because the domain of possible argv values (all valid C strings, which is to say, no strings containing NULs) matches the domain of possible filenames on common systems, this avoids introducing potential bugs.
- No generating text and piping that to an interpreter. This is an **extremely** error-prone technique, inducing shell-injection vulnerabilities: Consider what would happen if a PATH contained `/tmp/$(rm -rf ~)`, and that directory contained a `bash` executable.

Comment: Thank you, too. I have copied and ran your code, but the result only contains the version of the bash which shipped by macOS, it isn't fit my needs.